# Asymptotics of a transform

Tags: complex-analysis

I have come across a type of transform and I'm having a lot of difficulty proving the following is true or false. I'm not very well versed in asymptotics so I'm not sure how to prove this. I think that it is true, but I can't be sure. It's a little funky, and has to do with Mellin transforms.

The question goes:

If $\int_0^\infty g(t)t^{z-1}\,dt$ converges for $a<\Re(z)<b$ then if $f(t) = e^{-t} \int_0^t e^w g(w)\,dw$ does

$\int_0^\infty f(t) t^{z-1}\,dt$ converge for the same strip?

I know the result is true if $g(t) = O(e^{-\lambda t})$ for $\lambda > 0$, but other than that I am a little lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is an idea: $\int_0^\infty f(t) t^{z-1} \, dt = \int_0^\infty e^{-t} \int_0^t e^w g(w) \, dw \, t^{z-1} \, dt = \int_0^\infty e^w g(w) \int_w^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1} \, dt \, dw $, and $\int_w^\infty e^{-t} t^{z-1} \, dt$ is the incomplete gamma function.  Don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Stephen it is solved if we strengthen the condition:

If $\int_0^\infty |g(x)|x^{\Re(z)-1} dx < \infty$ and $f(t) = e^{-t}\int_0^t e^w g(w)dw$

Grabbing some basic asymptotics of the incomplete gamma function,

$|\Gamma(z,w)| \le C w^{\Re(z)-1}|e^{-w}|$

and as Stephen pointd out $\int_0^\infty f(t)t^{z-1}dt = \int_0^\infty e^{w}g(w)\Gamma(z,w)dw$

$|\int_0^\infty e^{w}g(w)\Gamma(z,w)dw|\le C \int_0^\infty |g(w)|w^{\Re(z)-1}dw < \infty$

Therefore, in the affirmative:

$\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{z-1}dx$ converges in the same strip as $\int_0^\infty g(x)x^{z-1}dx$